# Redis multi with bluebird promises

Tags: node.js, redis, promise, bluebird

Do you know a way for using redis client's multiple transactions command with bluebird promises?

Because, the following code never finishes.

```
  var $redis = require('redis'),
      $p = require('bluebird'),
      $r = $p.promisifyAll($redis.multi());

  $r.setAsync('key', 'test')
    .then(function(reply, data) {
      // ...
    });

  $r.exec(function() {
    $r.quit();
    process.exit();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing that is needed for the command not to hang is getting multi with a promisified connection before.

```
var $redis = require('redis'),
    $p = require('bluebird'),
    $r;

// this is important for bluebird async operations!
$r = $p.promisifyAll($redis.createClient.apply(this, arguments));

// multi also need to be promisifed with the promisified conn above
$r = $p.promisifyAll($r.multi());

$r.setAsync('key', '0').then(function(data) { });
$r.incrAsync('key');

// all of the above commands pipelined above will be executed with this command
$r.execAsync().then(function() {
  $r.quit();

  // this will make the console app (or whatever app) quit
  process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to run exec after these block finishes?

Hm, just chain it:

```
$r.pfaddAsync('key', item)
  .then(function(result) {
    // marked
    if (result === 0) {
      $r.incrAsync('dup');
    } else {
      $r.incrAsync('unq');
    }
    $r.exec();
  });
```

or maybe even

```
$r.pfaddAsync('key', item)
  .then(function(result) {
    // marked
    if (result === 0) {
      $r.incrAsync('dup');
    } else {
      $r.incrAsync('unq');
    }
  })
  .then($r.exec);
```

---

Or, if you want to execute it *after* the `incrAsync`s have finished, then it would be

```
$r.pfaddAsync('key', item)
  .then(function(result) {
    return $r.incrAsync(result === 0 ? 'dup' : 'unq');
//  ^^^^^^
  })
  .then($r.exec);
```

<sub>The `.then($r.exec)` might not work when `exec` is required to be called as a method, use `.then($r.exec.bind($r))` instead</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there are more elegant solutions? What if someone also need to add more commands after $r.pfaddAsync and does not related with pfaddAsync but in the end $r.exec should be called?

Comment: No, `then` is already quite elegant. If you want to call multiple, independent asynchronous functions and want to wait for all of them (before going on with `$r.exec`), you can use [`Promise.all`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise)